# Set names and collation UTF8 does not works in SimpleXML or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, utf-8, simplexml

I am gettin XML data which header has utf8 setted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I **download** it using **CURL** and it is downloaded correctly with UTF8 chars.

I **parse** that downloaded **xml** files using **SimpleXML** using this code:

```
<?php
```

class XMLParser{

```
public function __construct(){
}

public function parseFile($path){
    $xml = '';

    if(!is_null($path)){
        $file = file_get_contents($path);
        if(!is_null($file)){
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
        }
        else{
            echo 'there is no file';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'Wrong path!';
    }
    return $xml;
}
```

}
?>

And **send** it to **database** calling **PDO** and **stored procedures**, connect script has defined utf8:

```
$this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Each table has **utf8_general_ci**

But in table are chars like this:

> LeÃ³n de HuÃ¡nuco - Cienciano

**UPDATE**!
CREATE TABLE code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jcjdkdtaur`.`fixtures` (
  `Id` INT(32) NOT NULL,
  `UpdatedDate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateTime` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` date NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time` time NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `League` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeagueID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SportID` tinyint DEFAULT 1,
  `SportName` varchar(30) DEFAULT 'football',
  `Cup` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `EventName` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HomeTeam` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HomeTeam_Id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AwayTeam` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AwayTeam_Id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`HomeTeam_Id`,`AwayTeam_Id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

INSERT STORE PROCEDURE I CALL IT FROM PHP:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insupd_Fixtures;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insupd_Fixtures(IN p_id int(32), IN p_updated varchar(100), IN p_datetime datetime, IN p_date date, 
IN p_time time, IN p_status varchar(40),IN p_league varchar(255),IN p_leagueid int(11), IN p_sportid tinyint, IN p_sportname varchar(30), 
IN p_cup VARCHAR(20), IN p_country VARCHAR(60),IN p_eventname varchar(255),IN p_hometeam varchar(255),IN p_hometeam_id int(11),
IN p_awayteam varchar(255),IN p_awayteam_id int(11)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO fixtures(`Id`,`UpdatedDate`,`DateTime`,`Date`,`Time`,`Status`,`League`,`LeagueID`,`SportID`,`SportName`,`Cup`,`Country`,`EventName`,
`HomeTeam`,`HomeTeam_Id`,`AwayTeam`,`AwayTeam_Id`)
VALUES
(p_id,p_updated, p_datetime, p_date, p_time, p_status,p_league, p_leagueid, p_sportid, p_sportname, p_cup,p_country,
p_eventname,p_hometeam,p_hometeam_id,p_awayteam,p_awayteam_id)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
Id=p_id,
UpdatedDate = p_updated,
DateTime=p_datetime,
Date=p_date,
Time=p_time,
Status=p_status,
League=p_league,
LeagueID = p_leagueid,
SportID = p_sportid,
SportName = p_sportname,
Cup=p_cup,
Country=p_country,
EventName=p_eventname,
HomeTeam=p_hometeam,
HomeTeam_Id=p_hometeam_id,
AwayTeam=p_awayteam,
AwayTeam_Id=p_awayteam_id;
END //
```

Comment: which php version are u using ?

Comment: version is 5.6 i think

Comment: so your table has the correct format but data is not correct ?

Comment: Yes. Is problem maybe in simplexml? Maybe i need to set utf8 for SimpleXML? XML files are correct, so problem can be in SimpleXML or MySQL, but this is not first time that i using UTF8 inside db... 
Collation and Names are UTF8.

Comment: please update your question with `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` and an insert statement in PHP basing on your parsed `$xml`

Comment: before inserting data you should first print data with utf8_encode

Comment: utf8_encode does not work.

Comment: Alexey i call procedure for insert, procedure dont have defined utf8? Do i maybe need declare utf8 inside proc?

Comment: Instead of `$this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");` use `charset=UTF-8'` in the PDO constructor.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` for some of the Mojibake.  We need to see if the data was stored incorrectly, or fetched incorrectly.

Comment: Before inserting print the hex of the data:  `$hex = unpack('H*', $text);
   echo implode('', $hex), "<br>";`

Comment: How are you looking into your database? Where di you see the "wrong" characters? Might there be an encoding issue on your database-viewer?

Comment: HEX of baby.League for Seria A

Brazil: SÃ©rie A, 4272617A696C3A2053C383C2A97269652041

Comment: charset=UTF-8 result is same